# CF - Align text in a Label

Tags: compact-framework, label, alignment

Is there a way to align a text in a label to its absolute center (compact framework)?
Not a topCenter but a center of the label.

I want to avoid putting a label into a panel (container)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying OS (Windows CE) doesn't support vertical centering of statics, which is why it's not supported in the CF.  You'll have to eitehr manually center the label or just use DrawText on the "parent" and draw in the text you want without any underlying Label control at all.